# My Facebook picture is not syncing with Stack Exchange anymore

Tags: support, facebook, avatar

My avatar is empty, it's not syncing up with my Facebook profile picture, I checked the Facebook application and permissions, and saw it expired with Stack Exchange, I renewed it, but it's still broken. I have no idea why, and it's on all pages.